# increase width and height of table cells

Tags: javascript, html

I have created table dynamically using javascript, want to add a "href" link with the image to the table cell when table created dynamically and increase the width and height of the table cell.Please see "http://jsfiddle.net/c3X8Y/1/". In "Action" columnn of the table i want to display the href links and want to increase the width and height of the table cells.Below is the code.
HTML code:

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" id="fileUploadID" multiple/></td>
        </tr><br>
       </table>

     </td></tr>  <tr><td> 
        <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp; <table border="1" id="uploadTable" style="visibility:hidden">

           <tr> <th>SNo</th><th>FileName</th><th>Action</th> </tr>

  </table>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
    var rowN = 1;var count = 1;var a=1;
    document.getElementById("fileUploadID").onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById("uploadTable").style.visibility="visible";

        var fileNameIndex = document.getElementById('fileUploadID').value.lastIndexOf("\\");
        var file_name = document.getElementById('fileUploadID').value.substring(fileNameIndex + 1);

     // Get a reference to the table
      var tableRef = document.getElementById('uploadTable');

      // Insert a row in the table at row index 1
      var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(rowN);

      // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
      var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);

      // Append a text node to the cell
      var newText  = document.createTextNode(rowN);
      newCell.appendChild(newText);

      // Insert a cell in the row at index 1
      var newCell2  = newRow.insertCell(1);

      // Append a text node to the cell
      var newText2  = document.createTextNode(file_name);
      newCell2.appendChild(newText2);

         // Insert a cell in the row at index 2
      var newCell2  = newRow.insertCell(2);

      // Append a text node to the cell
      var newText2  = document.createTextNode('<a href="">delete</a>');
      newCell2.appendChild(newText2);


      rowN++;



    }
</script>
```

Comment: "and want to increase the width and height of the table cells". i didn't get that part. increase to what values..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an html element, you're creating a textNode in the following code:

```
 // Append a text node to the cell
  var newText2  = document.createTextNode('<a href="">delete</a>' +'<a href="">show</a>');
  newCell2.appendChild(newText2);
```

instead, you actually have to create html elements using `createElement()` function as follows:

```
 // Append a text node to the cell
 var newText2  = document.createElement('a'); //create actual HTML element
 newText2.innerHTML='show'; // set the elements properties
 newText2.href="#";
 newCell2.appendChild(newText2);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/c3X8Y/3/)

*this is just for demo purpose, you can actually create the remaining anchor and set all of their properties as shown above...*

**Update**

As for changing the size, simply specify it in css as follows:

```
td{
 width:250px;
 height:250px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/c3X8Y/4/)

**Update**

You can set the height and width of dynamically created elements as follows:

```
newCell.style.width ='250px';
newCell.style.height ='250px';
```

For displaying an image, instead of creating an `<a>` simply create `<img>` and set it's source and do your logic on it's click event.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3X8Y/5/)

Comment: @T J -  I want to increase the table cell widht and height to 250Px, as in my real application the table cells width is too small.

Comment: @user3692021 [check the update](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/c3X8Y/4/). it's better to reply for a comment right below it, otherwise other readers might get confused :D

Comment: @T j - it wont work for me as i have many other form fields in my page and i want to increase the width of tables cells which we created dynamically in jsfiddle. can you please suggest how to create an image with <a href> in Action column. As i need to display an image in Action column and when user clicks on image it has to perform some logic.Thankyou.

Comment: @user3692021 check the update.. first of all, this wasn't there in your question. next time when you're asking something, include all details initially..